# Docker put in simple language?

Tags: docker

I've been reading a lot about docker and am still quite confused what exactly its purpose is. I understand that it is a container to run/develop programs in. Is it similar to a git repository but just containerized? Or more like a virtualbox? How exactly does it function?

Comment: Hey Harrison, this is a good question but not for this site. We're more for straight questions and direct answers, so fully explaining the ins and outs of something like Docker is not really a good fit for the format. I'd recommend having a look through their tour, it's quite information-filled.

Answer (score -1):

Its a lot more like virtualbox then git.  It is a lightweight environment similar to a virtual machine (but less isolated and lighter weight) which has all the components needed to serve its functions - including the correct versions of libraries etc.

It functions by making use of Linux kernel extensions (namespaces) to separate it from the rest of the OS but run under it. Unlike a virtualboz VM it does not require a while OS install to work.

Comment: Can you run any application in it?